# How can I visualize a subgraph of a dask graph?

Tags: python, dask, dask-delayed

Given I have a really large task graph, `my_delayed.visualize()` either is impossible to generate or is too dense to be visually useful. If I have key for a particular task, can I specify a particular depth or x number of parents and children to visualize?

For example:

```
from dask import delayed
@delayed
def inc(x):
    return x + 1

def inc_list(x):
    return [inc(n) for n in x]

task = delayed(sum)(inc_list(inc_list([1,2,3])))
task.visualize(n_parents=1)
```

Would generate the below graph without the crossed out nodes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Short answer

No, this is not currently supported

#### Longer answer

The task graph is just a dictionary, so you could manipulate it however you like to visualize sub-pieces of it.  You might look at the dask.core functions `get_dependencies`, and `get_deps` to help manipulate the graph, as well as normal Python for loops.